# Ansible Vault and SSH not working together intermittently

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-vault

First I would like to say, PLEASE DO NOT LECUTRE ME ON SSH BEST PRACTICE.  I know the best practice.  This is a niche environment where keys aren't feasible and asking for password isn't feasible. There are legitimate and necessary reasons to use it this way.

Example Inventory:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_user=root
ansible_ssh_user=root
ansible_password="{{ vault_ansible_password }}"
ansible_ssh_password="{{ vault_ansible_ssh_password }}"
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'

[hosts]
myhost1 stuff
myhost2 stuff
```

My playbook is calling ansible.builtin.shell with delegate_to

If I put the actual password into the inventory it works fine
If I use vault to populate these values then it works most of the time and then it eventually stops and will never work again.
If I hard code the password again then it works
If I switch it back to vault, it starts working again until it doesn't
Rinse and repeat

If I use ansible-inventory to view a host's variables, the values are identical when I use a vault vs hardcoding the password.

Any idea why it would work intermittently?  Why having a successful run with a hard coded password would fix things so using vault works again?

I would expect it to always work or never work.  This behavior is problematic in an automated environment.

Comment: No playbook is shown, no OS version, no used software versions, no error message (just stating not working sometimes isn't one), no debug output ... With the currently given information and description I am not sure how someone should be able to answer. Especially because of "_If I use vault to populate these values then it works most of the time and then it eventually stops and will never work again_".

Comment: Just a guess and since your inventory shown contains Ansible variables with content assigned from Ansible variables, where are they come from and how and where are they defined? See [Adding variables to inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-variables-to-inventory).

Comment: How did you vault encrypt the password? Where and how is it stored? Ansible uses ssh master sessions by default. My guess is that your vaulted pass is wrong (with a trailing new line maybe...). You start with the hardcoded correct pass which initiates the session. You then switch to the wrong vaulted one with the illusion it works until the session expires.